# Replicating cell value with conditions

Tags: sql, r, azure, conditional-statements

am working on a db in SQL and have a table of the form:

```
    key  total  pmt    month
   ----  ------ -----  -------
    abc1  100    1       10
    ae10  1000   100      7
    etc.
---------------------------
```

I want to replicate the **pmt** value for every key starting from given month **up to month 180**, or less if the `sum(pmt) = total`.

Any idea on how to code this in SQL? (R would be ok as well).

Thanks

Comment: Is `sum(pmt) == total` on all rows or per-`key`? Do you mean that you have `month`s 7 and 10, and you want 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, ... 180 to be _added_ to the data in addition to querying the already-existing data? Does this data need to go back into the table or just returned in the query? I suggest it would be useful to reduce 180 (for now ) to (say) 12 and then please give us your expect _output_ given this existing data. Thanks!

Comment: Hi r2evans, sorry a few point to clarify:

 - I want it on all  rows (there are no duplicated keys)

 - starting point should be ```month```, hence for example I would get ```month 11 to month 180 for first row``` and ```month 8 to month 180 for second row```

 - no need to be _added_ to existing table, it can go into a new tmp table like #Temp

Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: sounds like you need a generator (and/or a recursive query), that is possible in most DBMSes but the mechanism differs for each; please include your DBMS type

Comment: I am on **Microsoft SQL Azure**

Answer (score 0):

I have SQL Server, not Azure, but I think this will work.

Sample data:

```r
library(DBI)
quux <- structure(list(key = c("abc1", "ae10"), total = c(100L, 1000L), pmt = c(1L, 100L), month = c(10L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
# ss <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
dbWriteTable(ss, "mytable", quux)
```

To demonstrate the basic capabilities of [`generate_series`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), I'll expand from `month` up to 12. Notice how `total`, `pmt`, and `month` all fill down, and `intvalue` (the value from `generate_series`) increments:

```r
dbGetQuery(ss, "
with cte_g as (
  select intvalue from generate_series(1, 12, 1)
)
select *
from cte_g join mytable t on cte_g.intvalue >= t.month")
#   intvalue  key total pmt month
# 1       10 abc1   100   1    10
# 2       11 abc1   100   1    10
# 3       12 abc1   100   1    10
# 4        7 ae10  1000 100     7
# 5        8 ae10  1000 100     7
# 6        9 ae10  1000 100     7
# 7       10 ae10  1000 100     7
# 8       11 ae10  1000 100     7
# 9       12 ae10  1000 100     7
```

We'll use `month` only to start the series, and then use `intvalue` as `month` for the rest of the query.

I'll expand up to 20 in order to not fill out this screen. This demonstrates how `ae10` stops when the `pmt2` (cumulative) meets/exceeds the `total`, whereas `abc1` continues through month 20 (where I artificially stopped it here):

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(ss, "
with cte_g as (
  select intvalue from generate_series(1, 180, 1)
),
cte_main as (
  select t.[key], t.total, t.pmt, cte_g.intvalue as month,
    sum(t.pmt) OVER (PARTITION BY t.[key] ORDER BY cte_g.intvalue ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS pmt2
  from cte_g join mytable t on cte_g.intvalue >= t.month
)
select * from cte_main
where pmt2 <= total")
#     key total pmt month pmt2
# 1  abc1   100   1    10    1
# 2  abc1   100   1    11    2
# 3  abc1   100   1    12    3
# 4  abc1   100   1    13    4
# 5  abc1   100   1    14    5
# 6  abc1   100   1    15    6
# 7  abc1   100   1    16    7
# 8  abc1   100   1    17    8
# 9  abc1   100   1    18    9
# 10 abc1   100   1    19   10
# 11 abc1   100   1    20   11
# 12 ae10  1000 100     7  100
# 13 ae10  1000 100     8  200
# 14 ae10  1000 100     9  300
# 15 ae10  1000 100    10  400
# 16 ae10  1000 100    11  500
# 17 ae10  1000 100    12  600
# 18 ae10  1000 100    13  700
# 19 ae10  1000 100    14  800
# 20 ae10  1000 100    15  900
# 21 ae10  1000 100    16 1000
```

Change the `20` to `180` and you'll fill it out to month 109 at which point `pmt2` is 100 (same as `total`).

I used brackets around `key` since it's a reserved word, marking it as a quoted identifier. (One could also use double-quotes.)